# Logic Flow name in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, power-automate, powerapps, azure-log-analytics

```
dependencies
| where type == "Ajax"
| where success == "False"
| where name has "logicflows" 
| project timestamp, name, resultCode, duration, type, target, data, operation_Name, appName
| order by timestamp desc
```

This KQL query in Azure Application Insights> Azure Log Analytics is used to get errors for logicflows. It returns the data but, I cannot see the logicflow name or ID anywhere. Is there any way to fetch logicflow ID?

The azure app insight is registered for a power app, where we are using automate flows to call apis. We need the flow's name in analytics.

I tried looking the database, there is no field for logic flow's name or ID. Though when seen in user>sessions, it shows name in requestHeaders.